# How to make iterative constraints using "for loop" in Python Pyomo

Tags: for-loop, optimization, constraints, pyomo

I am struggling on making multiple constraints using `for` loop in Python Pyomo.

My code concept that should be work well is below (this is not working).

```
bay_Alphabet={'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'}
for n in bay_Alphabet:
    def minUsePre_rule(m,u,v):
        return sum( m.X[u,v] for (u,v) in bay_setPre[n] ) == 1.0
    m.minUsePre+'n'=pe.Constraint(m.arc_set, rule=minUsePre_rule)
```

I want to make these four constraints by using `for` loop, `m.minUsePreA`, `m.minUsePreB`, `m.minUsePreC`, and `m.minUsePreD`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to create a single Constraint component indexed by bay_Alphabet:

```
bay_Alphabet=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

def minUsePre_rule(m,u,v,n):
    return sum( m.X[u,v] for (u,v) in bay_setPre[n] ) == 1.0
m.minUsePre = pe.Constraint(m.arc_set, bay_Alphabet, rule=minUsePre_rule)
```

If you really need to have separate Constraint components, you could also use the setattr() function to explicitly add a component.  For example:

```
bay_Alphabet=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
for n in bay_Alphabet:
    def minUsePre_rule(m,u,v):
        return sum( m.X[u,v] for (u,v) in bay_setPre[n] ) == 1.0
    setattr(m, "minUsePre"+n, pe.Constraint(m.arc_set, rule=minUsePre_rule) )
```

The latter approach is more complex to code, but it breaks out the constraints into different groups that you could use.